# OPENCV - Impossible to save or show a SurfDescriptor Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to save my Surf descriptors (of different images) `Mat` into a file, for later use using the code below:

```
int offline(int nb) { //creates descriptors image;
    Mat img;
    int nfeatures = 25;
    int nOctaveLayers = 2;
    double contrastThreshold = 0.04;
    double edgeThreshold = 10;
    double sigma = 1.6;
    SurfFeatureDetector surfDetector = SURF(edgeThreshold, 2, 2, true, false);
    vector< KeyPoint> keypoints;
    SurfDescriptorExtractor surfExtractor;
    Mat imgDescriptors;
    for (int i = 2;i <= nb;i++) {

        img = imread("images/" + to_string(i) + ".jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        if (!img.data)
        {
            return -1;
        }   
        surfDetector.detect(img, keypoints);
        surfExtractor.compute(img, keypoints, imgDescriptors);
        imwrite(to_string(i)+".jgp",imgDescriptors); //impossible to save
        //imshow("lol", imgDescriptors); //impossible to show
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i'm getting this exception : `OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension) in cv::imwrite_, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\highgui\src\loadsave.cpp, line 275` [RESOLVED BY adding the extension `+".jpg"`.

So i thought i should try to show the image, so i'm having another error:[image: show error]

Any clue about this ? (SECOND EXCEPTION)

Comment: to_string(i) just returns integer as a std::string , you should specify file extension, so imwrite knows what format it saves too. to_string(i) + ".jpg"

Comment: Same thing, it gets me to the second error :/

Comment: Don't save the descriptors as jpeg! Or any other image format... they are not an image. Use FileStorage instead

Comment: @Miki thanks! that worked well